# Two versions of user-specified exception filters that log a different message on match

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'd like to show you two versions of my two functions that support my logging tools. Their purpose is to log a different message (here `abort`) when an error occured and it matches the filter specified by the user. By default the `error` message is logged.

Version-1 of this code uses the classical `if` to handle the optional filter, while version-2 uses the a `try/except`.

### *Classical* `if`

The first function is an optional filter that logs an `abort` *trace* when the exception matches any of the error types specified by the user and returns `True` in this case, otherwise `False`:

```py
class LogAbortWhen:
    def __init__(self, *error_types: type[Exception]):
        self.error_types = error_types

    def __call__(self, exc: Exception, logger: TraceLogger) -> bool:
        if any((isinstance(exc, t) for t in self.error_types)):
            logger.final.log_abort(message=f"Unable to complete due to <{type(exc).__name__}>: {str(exc) or '<N/A>'}")
            return True
        return False
```

The other one logs the default `error` *trace* when there is no custom filter or the filter returned `False`:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def telemetry_context(
        activity: str,
        source: Source,
        on_error: Optional[OnError] = None,
) -> ContextManager[TraceLogger]:  # noqa
    parent = current_logger.get()
    logger = BasicLogger(activity)
    tracer = TraceLogger(logger)
    tracer.initial.source.append(source)
    token = current_logger.set(Node(logger, parent))
    try:
        yield tracer
    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        if not on_error or not on_error(e, tracer):
            tracer.final.log_error(message=f"Unhandled <{type(e).__name__}> has occurred: <{str(e) or 'N/A'}>")
        raise
    finally:
        current_logger.reset(token)
```

---

### Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission: `try/except`

But then I thought, how about rewriting it with the *easier to ask for forgiveness than permission* principle in mind, so I did the following (theoretical code):

The `LogAbortWhen2` now throws the `DoesNotApply` error when it didn't do anything:

```py
class DoesNotApply(Exception):
    pass


class LogAbortWhen2:
    def __init__(self, *error_types: type[Exception]):
        self.error_types = error_types

    def __call__(self, exc: Exception, logger: TraceLogger):
        if any((isinstance(exc, t) for t in self.error_types)):
            logger.final.log_abort(message=f"Unable to complete due to <{type(exc).__name__}>: {str(exc) or '<N/A>'}")
        else:
            raise DoesNotApply()
```

And the context-manager `telemetry_context2` doesn't check the return value anymore, but handles the two errors that may occur: `TypeError | DoesNotApply`. (the `TypeError` is for when the `on_error` variable is `None`; I know, I should implement an empty empty filter always throwing the `DoesNotApply` error)

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def telemetry_context2(
        activity: str,
        source: Source,
        on_error: Optional[OnError] = None,
) -> ContextManager[TraceLogger]:  # noqa
    parent = current_logger.get()
    logger = BasicLogger(activity)
    tracer = TraceLogger(logger)
    tracer.initial.source.append(source)
    token = current_logger.set(Node(logger, parent))
    try:
        yield tracer
    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        try:
            on_error(e, tracer)
        except TypeError | DoesNotApply:
            tracer.final.log_error(message=f"Unhandled <{type(e).__name__}> has occurred: <{str(e) or 'N/A'}>")
        raise
    finally:
        current_logger.reset(token)
```

---

Which version would you prefer? The first one with the `bool` return value and the additional `if` or the second one with the `try/except`? Also how strict are you about the *EAFP* principle? Do you often write your code `if`-free and favor `try/except`s?

Comment: Version-1 of this code can also be looked at on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/he-dev/wiretap-py/blob/version/7.0/wiretap/src/wiretap/telemetry.py#L13). Version-2 is currently not checked-in as it's an experiment... for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're not running your static typing tool in strict mode, limiting the benefits to static typing your code.
- When to use `*args` can be a bit of a tricky one.
  However if you're ok with taking a `tuple[type[Exception], ...]` then we can use [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which can automatically build a number of dunders for you.

  Additionally I think having the class be frozen (immutable) makes sense, and you can automatically make `__slots__` for increases in performance and memory usage.
- I think you want to use `BaseException` not `Exception`. Please familiarize yourself with [Python's exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), which shows all exception inherit from `BaseException`.
- `isinstance` takes `type[BaseException] | tuple[type[BaseException], ...]` as the type argument, meaning you don't need to use `any` and a generator expression.

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogAbortWhen:
    exceptions: tuple[type[BaseException], ...]

    def __call__(self, exc: BaseException, logger: TraceLogger) -> bool:
        if isinstance(exc, self.exceptions):
            logger.final.log_abort(message=f"Unable to complete due to <{type(exc).__name__}>: {str(exc) or '<N/A>'}")
            return True
        return False


# Example usage
abort = LogAbortWhen((KeyboardInterrupt, OSError))
assert abort(OSError("test error"), TraceLogger(...))
```

- *Personally* I like to use a single level of indentation for arguments to functions. I have always found the `):` and now `) -> ...:` to be enough visual separation.
- The `parent` to `token` section of the function doesn't seem to be using standard Python, so commenting is hard. However I don't think the code belongs in the function.

  Why can't `BasicLogger` have a method to build and configure the `TraceLogger`?
- I'm not sure what `OnError` looks like. However I imagine the class will look quite similar to `LogAbortWhen` and I'm concerned you have a lot of WET code and possibly some over engineering.

Overall I don't have too much to say at a 'micro' level. However at a more macro level I'm unsure why you don't add a context manager to `LogAbortWhen`.

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogAbortWhen:
    exceptions: tuple[type[BaseException], ...]

    def log(self, exc: BaseException, logger: TraceLogger) -> bool:
        logger.final.log_abort(message=f"Unable to complete due to <{type(exc).__name__}>: {str(exc) or '<N/A>'}")

    def __call__(self, exc: BaseException, logger: TraceLogger) -> bool:
        if isinstance(exc, self.exceptions):
            self.log(exc, logger)
            return True
        return False

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def handle_error(self, logger: TraceLogger) -> ContextManager[None]:
        try:
            yield None
        except BaseException as e:
            if isinstance(e, self.exceptions):
                self.log(exc, logger)
            raise


with LogAbortWhen((OSError,)).handle_error(TraceLogger(...)):
    raise OSError("test error")


@contextlib.contextmanager
def telemetry_context(
    activity: str,
    source: Source,
    on_error: Callable[[TraceLogger], ContextManager[Any]] = lambda t: contextlib.nullcontext(enter_result=None),
) -> ContextManager[TraceLogger]:  # noqa
    parent = current_logger.get()
    logger = BasicLogger(activity)
    tracer = TraceLogger(logger)
    tracer.initial.source.append(source)
    token = current_logger.set(Node(logger, parent))
    try:
        with on_error(tracer):
            yield tracer
    finally:
        current_logger.reset(token)


with telemetry_context(..., on_error=LogAbortWhen((OSError,))) as tracer:
    pass
```

### Comparative Review

A classic LBYL/EAFP example is reading from a file.

```py
# LBYL
if path.exists():
    with open(path) as f:
        data = f.read()

# EAFP
try:
    f = open(path)
except OSError:
    pass
else:
    with f:
        data = f.read()
```

The difference is one calls `path.exists` first.
However, EAFP is *better*. The LBYL code *has a race condition*, if the file doesn't exist when `path.exists()` is called and is made before `open(path)` then we will need to handle an OSError.

The bug free version of LBYL is just EAFP with more code:

```py
if path.exists():
    try:
        f = open(path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    else:
        with f:
            data = f.read()
```

Now lets look at your code:

```py
# LBYL
try:
    yield tracer
except Exception as e:  # noqa
    if not on_error or not on_error(e, tracer):
        tracer.final.log_error(message=f"Unhandled <{type(e).__name__}> has occurred: <{str(e) or 'N/A'}>")
    raise
finally:
    current_logger.reset(token)

# EAFP
try:
    yield tracer
except Exception as e:  # noqa
    try:
        on_error(e, tracer)
    except TypeError | DoesNotApply:
        tracer.final.log_error(message=f"Unhandled <{type(e).__name__}> has occurred: <{str(e) or 'N/A'}>")
    raise
finally:
    current_logger.reset(token)
```

Your EAFP is just LBYL but with more code.
So isn't a good use of EAFP.

Comment: The reson why `LogAbortWhen` isn't a context manager is, it's a parameter of another decorator as in [this](https://github.com/he-dev/wiretap-py/blob/version/7.0/wiretap/tests/test_traces.py#L281) test. The decorator tracks a function and the filter allows it to log an `abort` for known _abort_ exceptions instead of a false-positive _error_. Abort means a function wasn't able to do its job due to a known reason. Thus an abort and not an error so it shouldn't be logged as such.

Comment: I didn't know it was _legal_ to use data-classes this way! :o I thought they're meant _only_ for data. I guess I built an imaginary limitation to myself.

Comment: In other words, _abort_ means "no worries, it's not a _true_ error, everything's under control" ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm not really sold on your argument on why `LogAbortWhen` can't have a method to make a context manager. (Note: not "is a context manager") Does having the method `handle_error` cause some very odd duck typing issue in code you don't control? Why couldn't my final `LogAbortWhen` be a drop in replacement?

Comment: My _telemetry_ utility always logs at least two records: `begin` & `end` or `error` when an exception occured. The `LogAbortWhen` filter replaces the default `error` record with an `abort` record when I throw an exception myself (and don't forget to specify it in the decorator :P) so that it's not logged as an error. The alternative with the context manager wouldn't log the error if other exception occured. I think I should rename the parameter to something like `on_known_error` or  something mhmm. The `on_error` seems to be misleading.

Comment: @t3chb0t Ok so nothing is stopping you from using my final `LogAbortWhen` with your code. As the class supports both mechanisms.

Comment: Nope, I'm testing it actually right now ;-] I upgraded it to your version and need to think about the context-manager a little bit more... maybe there is something I don't see yet.

Comment: @t3chb0t Is the problem `OnError` was left out of the question and `LogAbortWhen` has significant differences? I'd like to remind you, the hypo/example/stub code close reason was introduced because when OPs leave important bits of context out, answerers have a tendency to write answers which are not applicable to the situation at hand. Then the OP complains the answer doesn't fit the actual code. If you want my opinion on if the approach I've suggested is good for `OnError` then you will need to post a follow up question.

Comment: You're right, I appologize. I should have stated more clearly that the question is primarily about the `if` vs `try/except` parts. I'm aware of the fact that I left some pieces out. On the other hand, including them all would blow the original issue and the question out of proportions so I thought it was acceptable to _ignore_ what's irrelevant to the question. Othewise it would turn into a review of the entire library and nobody has the time to study every bit. Trade-offs needed to be made :-\ On the good side your answer convinced me to drop the `try/except` experiment in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant the question to why the `BasicLogger` does not create the `TraceLogger` a rhetorical one so I'll just answer it... the `BasicLogger` provides the essential API and can theoretically be used on its own. `TraceLogger` on the other hand is the main API of that package and builds upon the general API. It wouldn't be a good idea to couple them and thus create a circular dependency.

Comment: @t3chb0t I think we both know 140 LOC is more of a snack then a meal. `BasicLogger` and `TraceLogger` are largely irrelevant to the context of the question. Inheriting and extending the base class (general API) in the extension (main API) doesn't create a circular dependency.